# Rails how to require the current password to allow user update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a rather difficult problem i want to update the user profile only if they submit the current password.I am not using devise.And another post here at stack overflow didn't really help me. 
This is my User controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_posts = @user.posts if @user
    if @user
      if @user_posts
        render 'show.html'
      else
        render 'show.html'
      end
    else
      render file: 'public/404.html', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully Signed up :-)"
    else
      redirect_to signup_path
      flash[:notice] = "You didn't sign up successfully :-("
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.id = @user.id
      render 'edit'
    else
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  :password == :password_confirmation

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

And this is my user.rb:

```
class User
  has_secure_password
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  def admin?
    self.role == 'admin'
  end

  def moderator?
    self.role == 'moderator'
  end    
end
```

Please help because I have been working with this for a long time now. And the other solution about this topic here at stack overflow didn't work.

Comment: If you're not using devise, where does this method in edit action come from '''current_user''' and what does it look like?

Comment: I have declared it myself at application controller

Comment: helper_method :current_user
  
       def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
       end

Comment: One problem is this '''if current_user.id = user.id''' should be '''if current_user.id == user.id'''

Comment: ok but that is not the real problem what should i add to make it editable only if you type the current password

Comment: What’s that `:password == :password_confirmation`? Please ask a clear question. You know how to get user input, don’t you? And you know how to verify the password, obviously. So I don’t see a problem.

Comment: I added that so that when you sign up you need to put the password and the password confirmation and that line :password == :password_confirmation makes it so that they are equal so that if you mistype you won't sign up

Comment: This question is not clear at all.  Stop and backtrack. Is authentication currently working?  If so, are you asking to prompt for a password again when the user attempts to update their profile? If so you would presumably want to check for that in the `update()` method in your controller, probably using the existing auth mechanism. Right now it just gets the user by id and then does the update with no checks.  If this doesn't make sense, then take some time to reformulate your question step by step, clean up your code examples, and show all relevant code, so that you can get meaningful help.

Comment: What you see in the code is my authenticate and it works i can login signup edit my account others can see it, but the problem is that when i update/edit my account it does't require me to enter the password that i currently have and i want this feature implemented. I don't know how to do it. If you can help please help cause i have been working with this for a long time now.

Comment: @HansiCollaku, You may want to read up on how to roll your own user authentication for Rails. I recommend something like this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch. Once you get that working (maybe you already have), you can do something like this: `user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])` on the first line of the `update` action in your controller above. Ideally you would define a `authenticate_user` method in your application controller and use a `before_filter`.

Comment: If you have seen my code correctly you might have noticed that i do authenticate with bcrypt. Please if you know how to require the current password ( how to even ask for it ) when you edit your account. Please if someone can help

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `virtual attributes`

#### 1. The User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current_password
end
```

#### 2. The form

add the `current_password` `attribute` to the `form` as a `text_field` `input`

#### 3. The UsersController

```
def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  if @user.authenticate(update_params[:current_password])
    # update the user
    # maybe check if the data are valid
    @user.update(update_params)  
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Please provide your password"
    @user.errors.add :current_password, "invalid"
    render :edit
  end
end

def update_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:current_password, :email)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i get this error 'When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.'

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a problem in your `edit` action:

```
current_user.id = @user.id
```

That assigns `@user.id` to `current_user.id` - you wanted `==` to test that it's the correct `User`. You should put a similar check on `update`, and probably extract it into a `before_action` so you can easily apply it anywhere you want to.

To check that the password is present, add it to your form like any other field and then get it out of `params` to verify it. That would look something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    encrypted = encrypt(params[:password]) # Using whatever your mechanism is
    if encrypted == @user.encrypted_password
      # Update the user
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Password is required to update user information.'
      redirect_to edit_user(path(@user))
    end
  end
end
```